# Opening logged in browser with selenium in python - No guest tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to open the chrome browser with selenium.The problem is it opens it only in guest account and i have been trying for days to find some argument or something else to add on to the code to open it on my Google account browser. Please help me if you can I will truly appreciate it!!

Comment: There's no such thing as a "Google account browser", but I assume you mean you are logged in to Google on the browser you normally use. You cannot open that with `selenium` (that would be a major security problem), but you *can* log the browser you open with `selenium` into your Google account, by having it visit the appropriate page and going through the needed forms - however, it's something you probably shouldn't do as it will involve adding your credentials to a script or data file and lower the security of your account to no longer require MFA.

Comment: Instead, you should probably look at what it is you're actually trying to get done, and see if there's an API available that allows you to do that in a safe and secure way.